# Devise login one model but two different layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

This can be a silly question, but it is freaking me out

suppose I have `admin` and `application` layout. And I have following codes:

```
# For admin layout
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end

# For application layout
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user, only: :index

  def index
  end
end
```

Now, I visit `/admin` and it will redirect me to `users/sign_in` unless I am logged in user. Similarly, If I visit `dashboards` same thing will happen.

> also note that, I am using `user` devise model for storing user info and `role` for storing user roles. That means, admin user can access `admin` layout and `other role` user can access `application` layout.

**Requirement:**

Just like, I have separated `admin` layout for admin user and `application` layout for `other role` users.

I want to separate login layout for `admin` and `application` layouts.

If user is accessing `/admin` then they should redirect to `admin` login layout and if user is accessing `/dashboards` they should redirect to `application` layout if they are not signed in.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a session variable in the Admin Base controller like:

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController

  # Set the admin layout
  before_action :use_admin_layout  
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  private 

    def use_admin_layout
      session[:admin_layout] = true
    end

end
```

Then in ApplicationContoller just set the layout like so:

```
layout "admin" if session[:use_admin_layout]
```

You will just need think about clearing the session for any NON admin controllers. Probably in a before_action. Just add this to your ApplicationConroller

```
private

    def clear_admin_layout
      session[:admin_layout] = nil
    end
```

And call it where necessary:

```
before_action :clear_admin_layout
```